# How do I construct a piecewise with the given information?

Tags: calculus

The average retail price of a gallon of gas in the Philippines is assumed to be 54.50 Php. In the a gasoline manufacturing company, individual gasoline retailers are only allowed a minimum of 100 gallons if they want to purchase from the company. If clients purchase over 100 gallons to 300 gallons, they will receive a 5% discount and a 10% discount if they purchase over 300 gallons to 400 gallons.Construct a piecewise function P such that P(x) gives you the wholesale price of gasoline

Comment: I would recommend you start by imagining an input value for the function. What is the price, for example, if you buy 200 gallons? How about 350 gallons? Start by considering these questions.

Comment: what do you mean?